# Symfony 4/JMS/FOSUser: Can't serialize datas from FOS\UserBundle

Tags: jms, symfony4, fosuserbundle

There is A LOT of similar quesions, some of them have validated answers, but here I am and none of them worked.

My use case is pretty simple:

- My users `App\Client\common\Entities\User` belong to a customer `App\Client\common\Entities\Customer`.
- `App\Client\common\Entities\User` also inherits `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User` which contains the holy property "email"

I want to serialize all my customers AND their users (including their mail). Jms works pretty well except i can not access properties from the `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User` class.

following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57679020/5677252) here is what I have now.

**jms_serializer.yml**

```
jms_serializer:
    #blablablaa....
    metadata:
        auto_detection: true
        directories:
            App:
                namespace_prefix: 'App\Client'
                path: '%kernel.project_dir%/serializer'
            FOSUB:
                namespace_prefix: 'FOS\UserBundle'
                path: '%kernel.project_dir%/serializer'
```

**serializer/App.Client.common.Entities.User.yml :**

```
App\Client\common\Entities\User:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        surname:
            expose: true
            exclude: false
            groups: [export]
```

**serializer/Model.User.yml:**

```
FOS\UserBundle\Model\User:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        email:
            expose: true
            exclude: false
            groups: [export]
```

**src/Command/DeploySyncUsersCommand.php:**

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $users = $this->customerRepository->findAll(); //this is an array of Customer
    $context = new SerializationContext();
    $context->setGroups(['export']);
    $serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
    $json = $serializer->serialize($users, 'json', $context);
    // do something with json
}
```

Everything works fine except the json does NOT contain email or any *FOSUser\User* data.

Also something interesting is that I can write anything (even invalid yml) in the App.Client.common.Entities.User.yml and Model.User.yml files, I'm able to clear the cache with no errors. I have errors when I write invalid yml in jms_serializer.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've been able to solve this using dependency injection instead of building the serializer

```
/**
 * @var SerializerInterface
 */
private SerializerInterface $serializer;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private string $reportAnalysisUrl;

public function __construct(SerializerInterface $serialzer, $reportAnalysis)
{
    $this->serializer = $serialzer;
    parent::__construct();
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $users = $this->customerRepository->findAll();
    $context = new SerializationContext();
    $context->setGroups(['export']);
    $json = $this->serializer->serialize($users, 'json', $context);
    //do something with json
}
```

so now my yml files aren't ignored anymore